# Zeta zeros and prolate wave operators

Tags: nt.number-theory, oa.operator-algebras, operator-theory

Recently, Connes, Consani and Moscovici in https://arxiv.org/abs/2310.18423 have blended two of their results on zeta zeros and the prolate wave operators, which, they say, "*suggests the tantalizing program of finding the semilocal analogue of the prolate operator. With such operator-theoretic tools in the semilocal case one could deal with Weil’s positivity*".

They in particular study semilocal Sonin spaces and say that it "*suggests that the obtained invariantly defined Sonin space should, when suitably equiped with a prolate type operator, play the role of the sought for Weil cohomology*".

The paper presents a candidate for the semilocal analogue of the prolate operator while another candidate linked to the metaplectic representation of the cover of a certain algebraic group is announced for a forthcoming paper.

Apparently these results were presented at a workshop at the Fields Institute last week http://www.fields.utoronto.ca/activities/23-24/operator-noncommutative

**Questions**: at the level of a beginning graduate student :

A) what is the Weil cohomology?

B) (judgemental, but hopefully not in a bad way), just to have an idea, does it feel like RH is in sight?